# Where does console output go in an IIS hosted app?

Tags: wcf, iis, console, console-application

Say I have a WCF app hosted in IIS.  And in that app I run this line of code:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Testing, testing 1 2 3");
```

Where will that be written to?  Or is it ignored and just lost?

Is there someway to capture it when needed?

Comment: If it's hosted in IIS, then it's the same as ASP.NET, so this post should answer it for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137660/where-does-console-writeline-go-in-asp-net  - I'd recommend using System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine instead, you have options to where that goes.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Nowhere.  More specifically:

> `NullStream`, which is defined as "A Stream with no backing store.".
>   All the methods do nothing or return nothing. It is an internal class
>   to `Stream`. The following code is taken from Microsoft's source code.
>
> Basically, when one of the `Console` write methods is call the first
>   time, a call is made to the Windows API function `GetStdHandle` for
>   "standard output". If no handle is returned a `NullStream` is created
>   and used.

quoted from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2075892/12744

actually, the same answer goes to on to address the second part of your question too:

> To actually redirect Console output, regardless of the project type, use
>
> ```
>   Console.SetOut(New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\ConsoleOutput.txt")),
> ```

Comment: The second part of this answer is a gem - it answers "How do I see Console output in an IIS Web app".   NOTE:  I found that I had to add "Console.Out.Flush();" after every Console.WrriteLine... call to get the output to show up in the file as soon as the WriteLine call is made.

Comment: There is just missing that part: "writer.AutoFlush = True"