# C# flush redirected console output

Tags: c#, redirect, visual-studio-2013, flush

I'm using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) approach to redirect the console output in C#. The problem is, it doesn't flush when I set a breakpoint in debug mode.

[Sol 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033648/c-sharp-redirect-console-application-output-how-to-flush-the-output), [sol 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415620/redirect-console-output-to-textbox-in-separate-program) and [sol 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256587/redirecting-output-to-the-text-file-c-sharp) are too complicated. I don't want to use the process class. Is there any simple way to flush the output in C#?

Or, since I'm using VS2013 for debugging, does anyone know if there is a `flush` button in VS2013 to flush the output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open the Immediate Window, Debug > Windows > Immediate Window.

Type in `Console.Out.Flush()` and hit `Enter`. This will invoke `Flush` on the output stream, on another thread, without interfering with your current breakpoint.

Comment: Coupled with the first answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009726/where-does-console-output-go-in-an-iis-hosted-app/9009837#9009837
This will let you see line-by-line output from an IIS Web app.  I'm trouble-shooting a package that works everywhere (Fwk, Core, Win, Linux...) except in IIS, where it throws an exception with no location or other information, so I'm lacing the package with Console.WriteLine(...);Console.Out.Flush();" to trace its progress and see where it's crashing.