# mixing Console.WriteLine and Debug.WriteLine in winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, console, console.writeline

From all I have read here, a non-console app (like a "Windows Application" by its project settings) should behave the same for Console.WriteLine and Debug.WriteLine in that they should both log to the VS output window when started in the debugger.

But I only get the output of Debug.WriteLine in the VS output window, when I have (in the main()) both:

```
        System.Console.WriteLine("test console");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test debug");
```

How can I directly "see" the console output?

When I change project settings to "Console Application", I see the messages in the additional console window.

Writing my own Redirection via a special TextWriter that passes on to Debug.WriteLine like [described in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5577749/586754) I at least see the output in the debug output window.

note: This is just a test-setup. In "real life" I have an external dll using the Console.WriteLine for outputting debug messages which I am interested in. On my side I am using Debug.WriteLine.

Using Windows 8 64bit, Visual Studio 2012, AnyCPU build.

Comment: "they should both log to the VS output window when started in the debugger." You heard incorrectly...

Comment: this is where I "heard" it http://stackoverflow.com/a/3012961/586754 but well my observations tell me you are right