# How can I tell dart to not show a shell/cmd window on windows in a dart command-line app?

Tags: windows, dart, command-line

I've created a Dart command-line app that is supposed to do some data fetching and synchronising in the background. But the problem is, every time it runs, it opens a shell/cmd window, which is annoying to the user.

Is there a way to not show this shell window on app start? How can I tell dart or windows not to show or open it?

Even without any output statements like print, the window still opens for the duration of the program run. I can't think of any way to avoid it.

Comment: On Windows, a *command-line* program *must* show a terminal window.  If you don't want a terminal window, make it a *windowed* program instead.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2628025/.

Comment: This might be helpful. https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way  The question I have linked is about hiding a batch file, but running a console Dart app is similar.