# Game window application with additional console window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

My previous demo was an XNA project that had a game window, as well as a console window for debugging information, however, the option is either not there or moved in a C++ project. Does anyone know how to enable a console window that will run alongside a game window in VS2010?

Comment: Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587767/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`AllocConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create a console for you process. Once you do that, you can use `std::cout` or, perish the thought, `printf` to write to the console.

Comment: `printf` would most certainly be superior to `std::cout` in terms of performance, which would be critical in debugging a game.

Answer (score 0):

You can view `Console` in `WinForms app` with the Visual Studio output window