# Outputting from a .exe to cmd

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, exe, std

I am writing a little program in c++ which creates an .exe which i then run by calling it with parameters in cmd. I want to be able to display output from the .exe into the cmd that I ran it from. I currently have this code which opens a new cmd window to display output which is close but not what i want. any help with this would be great! thanks.

```
AllocConsole();
DWORD NumberOfBytesWritten = 0;
WriteFile( GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), strLog1, lstrlen(strLog1), &NumberOfBytesWritten, 0);
```

Update:
I have also been able to write to a text file using  `dir > log.txt` in the command window when calling the program, is there a way I can change this so that it directs outputs to the console window? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My psychic debugging powers tell me that your build tools are configured to create your application in GUI rather than console mode.

If you reconfigure the build so that it generates a console mode application, you won't need to call `AllocConsole` or do anything special; you'll automatically be assigned to the console of the parent process.

Comment: Your not wrong its a win app! Ill convert this to a console app right away as i cant see any reason for it being a win app. Seems like the easiest thing to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try simple operations, such as:

```
std::cout << "Print me" ;
```

or

```
std::cerr << "Print me too";
```

?

(I hope I understood correctly that you want to print to the same console where you started your app)

Answer (score 0):

That question has already been asked: [How to output to the console in C++/Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587767/how-to-output-to-console-in-c-windows). Here is an answer that seems to be useful in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/587792/1728537

Comment: I looked at this thread before posting, from what i read it requires using allocconsole, this creates a new console window to put messages in where as i want them to appear in the original window it is launched from