# How do you copy everything from the console's output to a text file?

Tags: c++, console

I've tried Sink and SaveHistory to do this but none worked. I've also tried things such as the code from this question from one of the answers. [How to output to the console in C++/Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587767/how-to-output-to-the-console-in-c-windows). I made everything in an empty solution in Visual Studio 2019.

There weren't any errors but when I did:

```
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("Addresses.txt");
    myfile << printf << endl;
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
```

it printed out random numbers.

```
//Code I tried
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (int) {
    cout << "This will print to the console!" << endl; // I don't know how to make it read all of the output
}
```

My goal is to put the whole output of the console in the text file I selected. (Addresses.txt)

Comment: Unrelated: `myfile << printf << endl;` is high risk of causing people to freak out over the re-use of `printf`. Unless you really are trying to print the `printf` function. In that case, Why?

Comment: Might be simpler to leave C++ behind and use a redirect at the command line:  `MyProgram > myfile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

When you call `myfile << printf << endl` you aren't getting the text from the console, you are getting an identifier to the function. To get text from the console look at std::cin ex.

```
int x;
std::cin >> x;
std::cout << "You Entered: " << x << std::endl;
```

Sidenote, please avoid usage of `using namespace` this makes code much easier to read since it makes it clear if it is your function, or another libraries'