# Write to console and visual studios output?

Tags: visual-studio, console

In Winform Apps Console.WriteLine() writes to the IDE output tab. In a console app it writes to the console and not to the IDE output tab. For debugging reasons i find it easier if i can have i have a copy of the Console output (ATM i only use stdout) in my IDE. Is there an option to have Console.WriteLine() appear in both?

I use visual studios 2008 & 2010

Comment: 41 is better then my old 33 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122778/capture-console-output-for-debugging-in-vs).

As far as I know you cannot intercept StdIn, StdOut, and StdErr for console windows. You could use one of the options in the above link though (trace debugger, capture output, etc).

Another option might be to use something like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) to stream to a more convient source only those messages you care about.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept all output to the stdout by calling [`Console.SetOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout.aspx) and passing in a `TextWriter` of yours. From there, the sky is the limit. Or something like that.

But if this kind of message writing starts to get serious I'd suggest using a real logging library like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) or [NLog](http://nlog-project.org).