# View program output within the window of Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, redirect, output

I'm pretty new to C/C++ and to Visual Studio 2013. Actually, I'm a Java programmer and I am pretty much used to the way Eclipse outputs stuff: there is a small window within Eclipse that contains all the output whereas in VS a seperate console window is opened.

Is there a way to redirect the output to some kind of small window within the VS window aswell?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122778/capture-console-output-for-debugging-in-vs

Answer (score 0):

Use `OutputDebugString` -See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - Will send output to the output window in VS

Comment: It is indeed an option, but I don't think it answers the question which to me looks like "redirect command line project output like `printf`/`cout`to a VS window during debugging" (which I think not possible in stock VS).